# How to add Header and Footer in excel with vb.net?

Tags: excel, vb.net, interop

I'm learning vb.net and I try to do a small program to fill some cells in excel.
This is not so dificult and I could find too many information, but now I trying to insert an image to the Header of the excel and I don't know how.
I read all the documents in Microsoft webpage about "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" and I didn't success.

How can I add a Header?

Thank you very much for all your help.

---

I saw a property of this in de documents but I don't have success:

- HeaderFooter.Picture Property
- PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture Property
- HeaderFooter Interface

[Microsoft Office Interop Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with this code :

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'open excel document
    Dim App1 As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    'Start Excel and get Application object.
    App1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    App1.Visible = True
    'connection for package
    Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook = App1.Workbooks.Open("someExcelFile.xlsx")
    Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet = Wb.Worksheets(1)
    
    'Here you add Header and Footer in excel file someExcelFile.xlsx
    Ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&12&""Arial"" This is the &B&""Courier New""&16 HEADER &12&B&""Arial"" of Worksheet !!!"
    Ws.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&12&""Arial"" This is the &B&""Courier New""&16 FOOTER &12&B&""Arial"" of Worksheet !!!"

    Wb.Save()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! That works, and how can I insert a Picture with Ws.PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You have to add :  `code`  Ws.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = "D:\logo.png"
                           `code` Ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G"

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help!